# Battery draining rapidly

Tags: battery, ubuntu-core

I've recently switched From windows 10 to Linux. I am using Ubuntu 18 as primary OS on my Dell Inspiron 3542, battery drains so rapidly. I've used tlp and other battery optimization features. What should I do?

Comment: During my last check only three enteries were unoptimized others were good @dsstorefile1

Answer (score 0):

On my new Dell XPS 13 I have found that the screen brightness makes a big difference to the battery life, and by default it was fixed on max brightness (ie. shortest possible battery life). Turning the brightness down to around 2/3 made a big difference. Could it be that under Windows it was not on max brightness, or had an adaptive brightness, but on Ubuntu it is fixed on max brightness? (I have yet to master adaptive brightness under Ubuntu but haven't tried very hard yet, only observed that the default GUI doesn't have an option.)

Comment: Previously I was using Ubuntu alongside windows 10 and it's performance was pretty good battery timing was good but now I am using it as my primary OS and facing the above mentioned problem.